# powershell - get file, parse it and if "value=" < X then function sendMail

Tags: powershell

i have a text file that is automatically downloaded and updated with Task Scheduler.

It looks like this:

```
C:\PrintLog\GetUsageReportFromPrinterWebService\10.22.17.102:58:<input type="hidden" name="AVAILABELBLACKTONER" value="60">
C:\PrintLog\GetUsageReportFromPrinterWebService\192.167.10.140:58:<input type="hidden" name="AVAILABELBLACKTONER" value="80">
C:\PrintLog\GetUsageReportFromPrinterWebService\192.167.14.128:58:<input type="hidden" name="AVAILABELBLACKTONER" value="80">
```

I would like to:

1. delete "C:\PrintLog\GetUsageReportFromPrinterWebService\" and "input type="hidden" name="AVAILIBLETONER""
2. replace that IP adress with printer name (example 10.51.17.122:58 equals HP-01, 192.168.10.150:58 equals HP-02 etc)
3. **check if "value=" is smaller than 20 and if so than send an email with function sendMail**

It doesn't matter what is in that email (after that I will check it manually with webservice anyway).
I just need this as an remainder/alerter that some printer is getting low on toner, so I am not forced to manually check that txt file everyday(I most certainly would forget that :) ). These printers are offsite so I need to know in advance that the printer is low.

Note1: There are empty lines and spaces at the beginning of that txt

Note2: And no, there is no send report via email when low on toner to be configured on those printers (I double checked).

Note3: using C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

I guess point one and two are optional. The third one is important for me, I googled for something similar but just got lost as everyone wanted something little bit different.

Thanks

Comment: This site is not for people to write scripts for you.  You are supposed to show what you already have, and what is not working.

Comment: Well that is all nice and understandable (not being sarcastic), I have multiple ps1 scripts that I tried (most of them form this site) none of them does what I want. And since I have no knowledge of powershell syntax I am really not able to edit them to my liking. Are u saying that I should just repost them? Isn't that just a waste of more of your time for you to edit some other code than just start from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another possibility (I think it requires Powershell 4 because of Send-Mailmessage, but I could be wrong):

```
#requires -version 4.0

$logs = Get-Content "F:\scripts\ParseLog\file.log"

$warning = $false
$lowPrinters = ""

# Mail Settings
$Subject = "Low Toner Warning"
$To = "printeradmin@contoso.com"
$From = "admin@contoso.com"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.contoso.com"
$Priority = "High"

$printerList = @{
    "10.51.17.122:58" = "HP-01"; 
    "192.168.10.150:58" = "HP-02";
    "10.22.17.102:58" = "HP-03";
    "192.167.10.140:58" = "HP-04";
}

foreach ( $log in $logs ) {
    if ( $log -match '^C:\\PrintLog\\GetUsageReportFromPrinterWebService\\([^:]+:[^:]+):.*value="(.*)">$' ) {
        $printer = $Matches[1]
        $toner = [int]$Matches[2]
    }

    if( $toner -lt 20 ) {
        $warning = $true
        if( $printerList.ContainsKey( $printer ) ) {
            $printerName = $printerList[ $printer ]
        } else {
            $printerName = $printer
        }
        $lowPrinters += "Printer {0} has a low toner level of {1}.`n" -f $printerName, $toner
    }
}

if( $warning ) {
    Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -body $lowPrinters -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
}
```

Along about line 8 we setup some stuff for sending email.  Starting at line 15, we build a hash table mapping printer IPs/Ports with Printer Names (since printer queues aren't always listed in DNS, I decided to use a hash table instead).  On line 23, we use a regular expression to grab the ip and port, and the toner value by using the `-match` operator.  Stuff grabbed by the regex is stored in an array called `$Matches`.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you could do something like this:

```
$filePath = "C:\updatedFile.txt"
$prefix   = "C:\PrintLog\GetUsageReportFromPrinterWebService\"
$lines    = Get-Content $filePath |Where-Object {$_.Trim() -like "$($prefix)*"}

foreach($line in $lines)
{
    $content = $line.Trim().Substring($prefix.Length)
    $parts   = $content -split ":"
    $inputML = [xml]"$($parts[2])</input>"
    $inputValue = [int]$inputML.input.value

    if($inputValue -lt 20)
    {
        $printer = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress($parts[0]).HostName
        <#
            Your sendMail call in here
        #>
    }

}
```

You remove the "C:\PrintLog\GetUsageReportFromPrinterWebService\" part with Substring(), split it into 3 pieces, and then parse to last part as an `xml` element, giving much easier access to the `value` attribute

The IP to Printer name part will only work if you have reverse DNS in place already